# Is there any way that i can use 3rd party .net dlls in my xamarin application?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, dll, mono

Im trying to build my first xamarin application and wondering if i could use .net dlls in my xamarin application. is there any way that i can migrate .net dlls to mono libraries so that i can use in xamarin app?

Comment: When you say `.net dlls`, I'm assuming you mean CIL-based assemblies.... If so what type of assemblies are they? Framework 4.5/4.6/4.x/PCL/NetStd1.x/NetStd2.x/etc... ?

Comment: im trying to use "TechnologySolutions.Rfid.AsciiProtocol.Platform" dll, i believe its based on .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: `mono` tag added